# How to skip the first argument in $@?

Tags: bash, shell

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $@;
    do echo $i;
done;
```

run script:

```
# ./script 1 2 3

1
2
3
```

So, I want to skip the first argument and get:

```
# ./script 1 2 3

2
3
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use the offset parameter expansion

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "${@:2}"; do
    echo $i
done
```

#### Example

```
$ func(){ for i in "${@:2}"; do echo "$i"; done;}; func one two three
two
three
```

Comment: Note that whilst this works as advertised in `bash`, in Busybox (I used 13.2), which uses the `ash` shell, it _appears_ to work, but the offset counts characters rather than parameters. It's a bash question, so fair enough, but just a heads-up to those using other shells...

Answer (score 28):

Use the [`shift`](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch04sec14.html) command:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
FIRST_ARG="$1"
shift
for i in "$@";
    do echo $i;
done;
```

which skips the first argument:

```
# ./script 1 2 3
2
3
```

Comment: this is the right answer

Answer (score 4):

Look into **Parameter Expansions** in the bash manpage.

```
#/bin/bash
for i in "${@:2}"
    do echo $i
done
```

Comment: You'll want to quote `"${@:2}"` to protect arguments with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could just have a variable testing whether it's the first argument with something like this (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash
FIRST=1
for i in $@
do
    if [ FIRST -eq 1 ]
    then
        FIRST=0
    else
        echo $i
    fi
done
```